# как сделать чёрный цвет в окне прозрачным прозрачным (linux sfml c++)

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

в windows это делается так:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
//...    
SetWindowLong(getSystemHandle(), GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(getSystemHandle(), GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(getSystemHandle(), RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

а вот как сделать тоже самое в linux я не знаю.
дайте пожалуйста код, делающий чёрный цвет прозрачным, и какие файлы для этого надо инклюдить.
в интернете не могу найти этой инфы

Comment: а причём тут sfml?

Comment: в sfml вы можете нарисовать картинку с прозрачным цветом поверх чего то, но к окну это не применимо, если вам нужно чтобы окно программы просвечивало. Может это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395179/empty-or-transparent-window-with-xlib-showing-border-lines-only

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, где то в интернете я видел ответ: "qt". чтобы такого не было я уточнил.

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, то что по ссылке не помогло( (пишет, что неопределённая ссылка на символ «XMatchVisualInfo». даже если подключить библиотеку x11 через cmake пишет undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::setActive(bool)' (что странно))

Comment: sf::RenderWindow это sfml, библиотека sfml-graphics

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, вот потому это и странно. sfml то у меня подключен и прекрасно работает

Comment: ```inline bool TransparentRenderWindow::enableTransparency()
  {
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    
    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);
  
    XSelectInput(display, getSystemHandle(), StructureNotifyMask);
  
    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, getSystemHandle(), &wm_delete_window, 1);
  
    XMapWindow(display, getSystemHandle());
    return true;
  }``` где class TransparentRenderWindow : public sf::RenderWindow

Comment: возможно проблема в том, что ld делает только один проход по библиотекам, надо либо менять библиотеки местами, либо указывать, чтобы ld циклил, но не помню как это делать

Comment: вспомнил --start-group  --end-group

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, Нашёл из за чего ошибка. на linux нельзя наследоваться от окна (по крайней мере так, как это делал я)
но проблему это пока что не решило, окно создаётся прозрачным. но при перерисовке таковым быть перестаёт (даже если очищать с помощью Color::Transparent)